# Server replies with default debug response instead of raised exception response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Within an engine w/ an API, when querying the API an exception is thrown, but the server response is not using the response specified, and instead rendering a default debug response (in production).

I can confirm that the exception is caught by the controller:

```
Started GET "/api_v2/admin/submissions?system_id=123&spt_id=123" for 

127.0.0.1 at 2019-03-15 10:04:37 -0400
Processing by ApiV2::Admin::SubmissionsController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"system_id"=>"123", "spt_id"=>"123"}

[3, 12] in /....../emp_api_v2/app/controllers/emp_api_v2/application_controller.rb
    3: 
    4:     before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!
    5: 
    6:     rescue_from ::ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |e|
    7:       byebug
=>  8:       response(:standard_error, 500, "Hello World")
    9:     end
   10: 
   11:     def doorkeeper_unauthorized_render_options(error: nil)
   12:       { json: { message: "Not authorized" }, status: 403 }
(byebug) cont
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5220ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Emp::System with 'id'=123:
```

The server is expected to respond with 500 Server Error not the debug error stacktrace.

Why are there two responses, even though the controller catches the exception and runs a response method.

**NOTE**: This happens in dev and prod ! Server responds with 500 first (my catch response) but then with a stacktrace and 404 (As this is the source of the error and correct exception). It breaks my tests as the past response was 500. I was not able to revert my server to the old behavior by: reinstalling ruby, reinstalling rails + all gems + rolling back all changes throughout the repo. This behavior seems to be externally set by a ENV variable or something else.

I'd be grateful for any insight.

Edit: The (api) app controller looks like this:

```
module ApiV2
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::API

    before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!

    rescue_from ::ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |e|
      response(:standard_error, 500, "Hello World")
    end

    def doorkeeper_unauthorized_render_options(error: nil)
      { json: { message: "Not authorized" }, status: 403 }
    end
  end
end
```

**Edit 2**: I was able to get the correct response by wrapping the call in a rescue block. That code will result in a lot of begin/rescue blocks though as each of them has a specific error message.

```
    begin
      system =   Emp::System.find(sys_id)
    rescue
      render json: { status: 500, content: "Specific Error msg" } and return
    end
```

Originally i had a method as follows:

```
def handle_exception(message, &block)
  begin
    block.call
  rescue Exception => e
    render json: { message: message }, status: 500 and return
  end
end
```

This will result in double render error as it's not returning from the top-level method but from the block.

Comment: What does your application controller look like?

Comment: @dbugger: Added the API controller. What baffles me is that i can not reproduce the previous correct response state by reverting code changes to working branch. It seems to point to a configuration problem and actually not a code issue.

Comment: You don't have another rescue_from lying around somewhere?

Comment: @dbugger: not really. I do have multiple rescue_from but they respond to other specific exceptions. I could get some insight though, see edited Q.